# Cordova fixed width and height android

Tags: android, cordova, viewport

I was trying to create a cordova app,and i was set the meta tag as follows,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500,height=500 initial-scale=1.0">
```

I need to display my application content in 500 X 500 dimension on all devices.Is it possible?

I know cordova using android webview to output the app.but this is fixed on the device width and height .Is there any way to change this?

Comment: What is your question? It is misleading, you're talking about wanting to change the device width and height, yet want the content to fixed on 500x500 on all devices?

Comment: Ya i need to set the app content width fix to 500 X 500

Comment: I think cordova is using android webview.In which file we have to specify the size?

Comment: not necessarily, the webview will scale up/down, recommended that height and width be set to 1, set the html body's width to 500px.